# How to pass data between routed components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular10

I have a routed component like this:

[image]

From component A: I have an object that was fetched through an API, At the moment I have a button that is redirecting me to Component B.

There is no parent child relationship between components A and B.

What I want to do is to send that object while redirecting to component B, So I can work on it.

**I don't want to pass the data through the URL** like this:

```
 return this.router.navigate(['associate-product/' + this.id, {this.data}]);
```

*Also I don't want to store the object on LocalStorage.*

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: When you say "There is no parent child relationship between components A and B." Do you mean that you don't use a service ? And if you don't use one, is it because you didn't heard about it or because you really don't want ?

Comment: I didn't heard about it, is there a service that can achieve this ?

Comment: A service is a ts file which is used by some components that use same variables/methods. This file allow you to share data through components just by injecting the service in them.

Comment: How Can I, Inject the service ? 
I have a service that will call the api on component A, I have the function that will construct the object that I need on the component B, how can i send it ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57355485/11122892) worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Using Routing**

If you want to pass data from one component to another using routing, you can use `NavigationExtras`.

In CompA you can do:

```
constructor(private router: Router){
}

goToCompB(){
  this.router.navigate(['route_to_comp_b/' + `${params_if_any}`], {
    state:{
      data: yourDataToShareWithCompB
    }
  });
}
```

In CompB you can do:

```
constructor(private router: Router){
 const data = router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.data;
}
```

PS: You can also use service based pattern as answered by others

Answer (score 0):

you can use a service with Subject/ Behavior in order to achieve that, like described in their [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

Using service, you can share data through your components that injects the service.

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vg8bib) with a little example of possibility to share the data and to know when the data is retrieved from API.

On this example, you have 2 components, A and B, and a service, "example".

On your first component (A) you call the API to get data, on the example I've made a seTimeout to simulate an asynchronous call.

Then, when the call is finished, a button to move to b can be shown, and on component b there is the data that was retrieved from the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `state` object from `NavigationExtras`. Like others have mentioned

```
this.router.navigate(['your-component-route'], {
 state:{
   myComplexObject: dataObject
  }
});
```

Then fetch that object in other component like

```
constructor(private router: Router){
  const data = router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.myComplexObject;
}
```

**

### IMPORTANT:

**
Its worth mentioning here that this `router.getCurrentNavigation()` only has value in `**constructor**`, otherwise one won't be able to access in onInit.
Hope this helps