# Send data from one componentA to componentB on clicking at a place in componentA (through angular service)

Tags: angular

I am working on a simple music app. Now in the app I have two components , one is a home componentA that contains the audio player(meaning the volume bar , seek bar , play pause etc..) and the other componentB that has all the songs.

My objective is that whenever someone clicks on a song on componentB(that is a list of songs) immediately the details of that song(url,img etc..) are sent to componentA so that the song start playing.

this is my **componentB.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let song of songs | filter:searchText" 
      (click)="songSelected(song.url,song.name)">
      <img src="{{song.img}}">
      <div>
        <p><strong>{{song.name}}</strong><br>
        <h6>{{song.singer}}</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**songSelected()** above is working fine.

This is my **componentB.ts**

```
  songSelected(url: string,name:string){
      this.selectedurl=url
      this.selectedname=name
      this._allsongs.setData(this.selectedurl,this.selectedname);
      
  }
  constructor(public _allsongs:AllsongsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.songs=this._allsongs.getSongs();
  }
```

and this is my **service.ts**

```
setData(url: any, name: any) {
    console.log("From Service set data previous = " + this.name)
    this.url = url;
    this.name = name;
    console.log("From Service set data new = " + this.name)
  }

  getData(): any {
    return [this.url, this.name]
    
  }
```

And this is my **componentA.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.songurl=this._allsongs.getData()[0];
   this.songname=this._allsongs.getData()[1];
  }
```

NOw what problem I am facing is that ngOnInit only works when component is initialised so when someone clicks on the song in componentB the song details are not sent using getdata.
Please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use in your service a Subject and subscribe in your component A, see an example of Subject in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355066/how-to-implement-behavior-subject-using-service-in-angular-8)

Your service

```
  private mySubjectSource = new Subject<any>();
  myObservable=this.mySubjectSource.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  sendValue(value:any)
  {
    this.mySubjectSource.next(value);
  }
```

Your component A, in ngOnInit

```
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.myService.myObservable.subscribe(res=>{
      ..make something with the response...
    })
  }
```

Your component B

```
   constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
   sendValue(value:any)
   {
     this.myService.sendValue(value);
   }
```

A [fool example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdvrjs?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-song.component.ts)

Comment: Ok But how do I send the data I want to send instead of (value:any) I want to send multiple values like url name img as strings

Comment: "value" can be an object: `(click)="sendValue(song)">`

Comment: Can u give an example in my case pls

Comment: it's a fool example, but I hope can help you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdvrjs?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-song.component.ts

Comment: Instead of sending an object can I send multiple variables like instead of song I want to send songurl and songimage seperately so how odes it take two or more parameters

Comment: you can create "onfly" the object, but you only can send an object or a variable, but you can destructuring the response. I updated the stackblitz to show an example