# When pass a selected item through a shared service between to component, how to respond all changes, not just onInit?

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, data-sharing, sharedservices

Mg goal is when I select an item from dropdown, which is in a button component, then it passes the item to a table component throughout a shared service. I need this to change the table by just showing the selected element. Now, if I select the element, it changes the service data to the selected item, but the table component checks the service data onInit (when nothing is selected yet), and if I select an item, it doesen't checks again. Just once on init. What should I do to make the table component constantly watch if the service data changed? I thought about observable, but I don't know how to implement it in my code.

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SharedDataService {
  selectedData: object = {};

  constructor() {}

  setSelectedData(data: object) {
    this.selectedData = data;
  }

  getSelectedData() {
    return this.selectedData;
  }
```

Button Component:

```
  onSelect(company: any) {
    for (var i: number = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      if (this.items[i].id == company.target.value) {
        this.selectedCompany = this.items[i];
        this.sharedData.setSelectedData(this.selectedCompany); //pass data to service
      }
    }
  }
```

Table Component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onGetItems();
    this.selectedCompany = this.sharedData.getSelectedData();
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.selectedCompany).length === 0) { //if nothing was selected
      //do nothing
    } else {
      //refresh the table with displaying that one item only
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use Observables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just get and set a variable in a service switch to using rxjs [behavior subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject). So with this you can just subscribe to the variable in the service where you can listen to all the changes.

You can find a similar example here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57355485/7203750